# Why wrapping children in a container doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to wrap the children of some elements in a new div and it's not working.
When I loop through the children of the element, the loop only loops through 1 element.

It wraps only one child and leaves the other.
Why?

```js
var homepageRows = document.querySelectorAll(".span-12 > *");

homepageRows.forEach(function(row){
    var newRow = document.createElement("div");
    newRow.className = "wrapper-row";

    row.childNodes.forEach(function(child) {
       newRow.appendChild(child); 
    });
    row.append(newRow);
})
```

```html
  <div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">
<div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
</div>
<div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
</div>
<div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a lot of content there, in your HTML, to parse; could you (re-) read the "*[mcve]*" guidance (with particular reference to the *minimal*) and reduce your code to the smallest amount necessary to demonstrate your problem? Does this demonstrate your problem: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n917jvpu/)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you want to achieve? "children of some elements" does not exactly provide all the details needed in order to understand the expected result and the problem at hand.

Comment: Will update the HTML code to make it easier to understand

Comment: So, the two <div> elements inside of the `.row.sqs-row` elements should **both** be wrapped *together* in a `.wrapper-row` element, or should each element be wrapped individually in its own `.wrapper-row` element? It would probably be helpful to post the desired outcome HTML to your question also, and thank you for your edits!

Comment: Yes, both should be wrapped together in a `.wrapper-row` :)

Comment: The key issue here (and the cause of lots of spooky DOM behaviour) is that `row.childNodes` is a live list of nodes — which means it will directly update as the DOM is modified. As you `newRow.appendChild(child)` during the loop, you confuse the forEach. Better to operate using a non-live list here, so `[...row.childNodes].forEach` will probably fix it.

Comment: If you read the title of this question out of context... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows, with some comments in the code to try to explain:

```js
let homepageRows = document.querySelectorAll(".span-12 > *");

homepageRows.forEach(function(row) {
  let newRow = document.createElement("div");
  
  // here we use the Element.classList API to add a new class-name:
  newRow.classList.add("wrapper-row");

  // the easiest change is to simply substitute `row.children` (which retrieves
  // a list of the element-children of the current `row` element-node; we use
  // an Array-literal and the spread operator to convert the iterable HTMLCollection
  // into an Array in order to use Array.prototype.forEach() (there is a
  // NodeList.prototype.forEach(), which is available to chain to the returned
  // value of document.querySelectorAll(), but there is no
  // HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach() which means it's easier to use the Array version.
  [...row.children].forEach(function(child) {
    newRow.appendChild(child);
  });
  row.append(newRow);
})
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.wrapper-row,
.wrapper-row * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col sqs-col-12 span-12">
  <div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row sqs-row">
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
    <div>Wrap me in .wrapper-row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
- [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `querySelectorAll` is already an array, namely the array of all elements of that match your query. So in your case, presumably, it's just one. What you want to do, I believe, is not to iterate over that array, but over all children of the first element (the one you want):

```
var homepageRows = document.querySelectorAll(".span-12 > *");
homepageRows.childNodes.forEach(function(row){
   ...
})
```